# pass 2D array slices from 3D array to a function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to pass **3 types of slices**:

[image]

In the main function:

```
winner = check_for_winner_slice(&arr3D[Z][0][0], X, Y) || check_for_winner_slice(arr3D[0][X][0], Z, Y) || check_for_winner_slice(arr3D[0][0][Y], Z, X);
```

The function:

```
int check_for_winner_slice(char arr2D[N][N], int row, int col);
```

but I'm having troubles doing that: expected `'char (*)[4]'` but argument is of type `'char *'`.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to use `code` syntax for better readability.

Comment: @ja72 And, notably, to **include code at all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `arr3D` has been declared as something like

```
char arr3D[M][N][N];
```

then the expression `arr3D[i]` will have type `char [N][N]`, which under most circumstances will "decay" to an expression of type `char (*)[N]`.

So all you should need to do is change your function call to

```
winner=check_for_winner_slice(arr3D[Z], X, Y);
```

**EDIT**

Slicing along the other two dimensions will require you to create a temporary 2D array:

```
char temp[N][N];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    temp[i][j] = arr3D[i][X][j];

winner = check_for_winner_slice( temp, Z, Y );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
    temp[i][j] = arr3D[i][j][Y];

winner = check_for_winner_slice( temp, Z, X );
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are passing wrong argument to your function. `&arr3D[Z][0][0]` is of type `char *` (as compiler warns you about this) but your function expects `char (*)[4]` type.
Pass `arr3D[]` (is of type `char (*)[N]`, I think `N` is (macro) `4` here.) instead

```
winner=check_for_winner_slice(arr3D[], X, Y);
```